# Initialize `ManipulationStationHardwareInterface` with lcm message

Tags: drake

I am trying to use drake to control a kuka iiwa robot and use the `ManipulationStationHardwareInterface` for Lcm communication. Before deployment on the real robot, I use `mock_station_simulation` to test. One thing that I find is that after initializing the simulator (which I think should trigger the initialization event?), Eval `HardwareInterface`'s output will give the default values instead of the current lcm message values. For example,

```cpp
drake::systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;
  auto *interface = builder.AddSystem<ManipulationStationHardwareInterface>();
  interface->Connect();
  auto diagram = builder.Build();

  drake::systems::Simulator<double> simulator(*diagram);
  auto &simulator_context = simulator.get_mutable_context();
  auto &interface_context = interface->GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(&simulator_context);
  interface->GetInputPort("iiwa_position").FixValue(&interface_context, current_position);

  simulator.set_publish_every_time_step(false);
  simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0);
  simulator.Initialize();
  auto q = interface->GetOutputPort("iiwa_position_measured").Eval(interface_context);
  std::cout << "after initialization, interface think that the position of robot is" << q << std::endl;
```

`q` will be a zero vector.
This behavior bothers me when I try to use the `robot_state` input port of `DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator`. `DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator` will use this q to initialize its internal state rather than the robot's real position. The robot will move violently. As a workaround, I need to read the robot's position first and use the `SetPositions` method of `DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator` and do not connect the `robot_state` input port. Another thing is that `LogVectorOutput` will always have the default value as the first entry, which is of little use.

I think this problem should be related with the `LcmSubscriberSystem`. My question is that is it possible to use the `Lcm` message to initialize the system rather than using the default value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting (and very reasonable) question. I could imagine having an initialization event for the `LcmSubscriber` that blocks until the first message to arrive. But currently I don't believe that we guarantee the order of the initialization events in a `Diagram` (likely the order is determined by something like the order the system was added to the Diagram, and we don't have a nice mechanism for setting it). It's possible that the diff IK block could initialize before the `LcmSubscriber`.

In this case, I think it might be better to capture the first `LcmSubscriber` message yourself outside the simulation loop, and manually set the diff IK integrator initial state. Then start the simulation.

I'll see if I can get some of the other Drake developers to weigh in.